# How to add dropdown for product qty in update cart page in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, addtocart, qty, dropdown-options, update-cart

I added dropdown for product qty box in addtocart.phtml like below:

```
<div class="field qty">
        <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?></span></label>               
        <select name="qty" id="qty" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" 
               class="input-text qty" data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>">
               <?php $i = 1 ; ?>
                <?php 
                 while( $i < 500) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * $i; ?>"><?php echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * $i; ?></option>
                    <?php $i++; ?>
                 <?php } ?>
        </select>

    </div>
```

But I also want to implement same in updatecart.html in magento 2. How to do that?

[image]

Comment: In which file updatecart.html or updatecart.phtml

Comment: in updatecart.phtml file

Comment: you can add image how to want to you show???

Comment: I uploaded the image. Please check it.

Comment: try this same as updatecart --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148354/dropdown-for-add-to-cart-qty-in-magento-2

Comment: Thank you. Now it is working.

Comment: above comment link i convert into answer and you kindly accept answer ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing correctly.

First copy `updatecart.phtml` file from `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/configure/updatecart.phtml` file and put it in your theme at `app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/configure/updatecart.phtml.`

**code as per requirement.**

Just replace div in that file

```
<div class="field qty">
   <label class="label" for="qty">
       <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span>
   </label>
   <div class="control">
       <select name="qty" id="qty" title="<?php echo __('Qty') ?>" 
            class="input-text qty" data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>">
                <?php $i = 1 ; ?>
                <?php 
                while( $i < 500) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * $i; ?>"><?php echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * $i; ?></option>
                    <?php $i++; ?>
                <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now it is showing the qty box values as 3,6,9,12 in that way.

Comment: getProductDefaultQty gets the previously entered qty value.