# Shared wishlist items in email not display images in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates, wishlist, addtowishlist

When I share List product in my wishlist to Friend list, Everything ok, but Image can't render in the mails.

The images are broken in the mails of the shared wishlist.

[image]

Comment: try to get the current links of images in email by inspecting element browser. I think the `https` may be the issue.

Comment: My development site is in http version. So I think you are right.

Comment: i add the answer and you accept my answer...

Comment: Okay. And also answer this one -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312911/how-to-add-dropdown-for-product-qty-in-update-cart-page-in-magento-2/312936#312936

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this issue is possible like -

Try to get the current link of image in email by inspecting element browser. I think the **`HTTPS`** may be the issue.

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 0):

regarding mine, it doesn't have a wishlist image code.

below is the sample code for my wishlist email of mine.

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<p>{{trans "%customer_name wants to share this Wish List from %store_name with you:" customer_name=$customerName store_name=$store.frontend_name}}</p>

{{depend message}}
<table class="message-info">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h3>{{trans "Message from %customer_name:"customer_name=$customerName}}</h3>
            {{var message|raw}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
{{/depend}}

{{var items|raw}}
<br/>

<p><a href="{{var viewOnSiteLink}}">{{trans "View all Wish List items"}}</a></p>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```